# Gigya response "Last identity cannot be removed"

Tags: facebook, gigya

I tried to perform 
https://socialize.us1.gigya.com/socialize.removeConnection?provider=facebook&...

this are parameters I've copied from Chrome devTools:

- provider:facebook
- lastIdentityHandling:soft
- removeLoginID:true
- APIKey:{someKey}
- login_token:{someToken}
- authMode:cookie
- gmid:{someGmid}
- ucid:{someUcid}
- sdk:js_5.8.10
- format:jsonp
- callback:gigya._.apiAdapters.web.callback
- context:R1452017714731_0.4621349780354649

I think first 3 is more important.

The problem, that I received different responses, when tried to run it locally and from host. I was told, that gigya is configured the same way.

locally all is good:

> gigya._.apiAdapters.web.callback({
>     "statusCode": 200,
>     "errorCode": 0,
>     "statusReason": "OK",
>     "callId": "693bb63e639f409691925e207d8a180e",
>     "time": "2016-01-05T18:15:14.024Z",
>     "context": "R1452017714731_0.4621349780354649"
>   });

host shows this

> gigya._.apiAdapters.web.callback({
>     "errorMessage": "Not supported",
>     "errorDetails": "Last identity cannot be removed",
>     "statusCode": 400,
>     "errorCode": 400096,
>     "statusReason": "Bad Request",
>     "callId": "43856e53efad4ef3890a8671b96f6006",
>     "time": "2016-01-05T18:16:16.695Z",
>     "context": "R1452017777589_0.7615769929252565"
>   });

Can anybody tell me what this mean

> "errorMessage": "Not supported",
>     "errorDetails": "Last identity cannot be removed"

Thanks in advance.

UPD: Setting removeLoginID to false helps somehow. Issue solved. If anyone can explain better - don't be shy.

Answer (score 1):

Each Gigya user can have multiple identities -- one for Facebook, one for Google+, one for Twitter, etc. You can call removeConnection on any of these identities as long as that identity is not the last remaining identity on the user record. The user always has to have at least one identity.